# Python script to determine free space provides inaccurate results

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script (below) that is not providing accurate results.  I am sure I messed something up but cannot seem to figure it out. I would appreciate any input or advice.

The purpose of the script is to report a remaining percent of total disk space on a specific mount point.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os 
disk = os.statvfs("/Volumes/Promotions/") 
totalBytes = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_blocks) 
totalUsedSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*(disk.f_blocks-disk.f_bfree)) 
totalAvailSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_bfree) 
used = float(totalUsedSpace/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024) 
avail = float (totalAvailSpace/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024) 
total = float (totalBytes/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024) 
percent = ((used)/(total)*100)

import smtplib

SERVER = "webmail.****.com"

FROM = "***@***.com" TO = ["***@***.com"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "Total Available Remaining Percent Full\n" "%.2fTB" % (total) + " " "%.2fTB" % (avail) + " " "%.2fTB" % (used) + " " "%.2f%%" % (percent)

# Prepare actual message

message = """\ 
From: %s 
To: %s 
Subject: %s

%s """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER) 
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message) 
server.quit()
```

The above sends output of the following:

```
Total 0.2TB Available 0.00TB  Remaining 0.01TB  Percent Full 83.12%
```

The issue is the path above is actually 138 TB in size with 23.3 TB available

Any input or advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you!
Terry

Comment: Why are you dividing by 1024 5 times in the `float` lines? 1 TiB is `1024**4` bytes, not `1024**5`.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "Remaining"?

Comment: gnibbler - I mistyped Remaining - thank you for pointing that out.  I intended to put used.

Comment: As a Note: os.statvfs is deprecated, and removed in Python 3. Since this function only works on Linux/OSX anyway, you should just consider using `subprocess` and the unix `df`. This will simplify you life a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Tb = kb * kb * kb * kb

You are using 5 divisions by 1024 which would express bytes as Petabytes instead of Terabytes.

better use a conversion function:

```
def asTb(numberOfBytes):
  TB = 1024**4
  return numberOfBytes / TB
```

Comment: Thank you and tepples above.  I got a bit excited typing 1024's obviously.  That has cleaned it up a bit, it is now showing closer but something is still off as the actual size is 138TB - This is what I am getting.   total: 16.88TB available: 2.85TB Used 14.03TB Percent Full: 83.12%